# List select mysql

Tags: php, jquery

I have a database with soccer teams. I get all this teams in a list like this :

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <select name="team1">
    <option value="1">England</option>
    <option value="2">Spain</option>
    <option value="3">Italia</option>
    <option value="4">Germany</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I want to made some soccer matches between this teams. So, I choose a team in this 1st list and I chose the other team in the 2nd list.

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <select name="team2">
    <option value="1">England</option>
    <option value="2">Spain</option>
    <option value="3">Italia</option>
    <option value="4">Germany</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

But I want that in the second list, there is all teams except the team that I select in the first list. Can you help me please ? thank you !

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: I don't tried something because I don't made this kind of thing until now. Help me please.

Comment: On StackOverflow we are here to help you with your questions, not to do your job. Hence we ask people to show that they've put effort into solving their own problem, without us feeling like we're just doing the dirty work. Nothing personal, but you probably wouldn't like someone else asking you do to their job either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("select[name=team1]").on( 'change', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("select[name=team2] option[value="+val+"]").hide();
    $("select[name=team2] option").not( "option[value="+val+"]" ).show();

    $("select[name=team2]").val( $("select[name=team2] option:visible").val() );

});
```

1. hide selected option
2. show all other options
3. set value to first option that is visible

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

*(i gave an id to both select)*

```
$('#team1').change(function(){
    $('#team2').find('option[value*="'+ this.value +'"]').remove();
}).change();
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7dxtd/)

#### updates:

I have added default option in both teams:

```
<option value="0">Select team1</option>  //<----in team 1
<option value="0">Select team2</option>  //<----in team 2

$(document).ready(function(){
  var options = $('#team2').html(); //<--cache your options for team2 here outside
  $('#team1').change(function () {
     if (this.value !== '0') {
       $('#team2').find('option[value*="' + this.value + '"]').hide();//<-hide here
     } else {
       $('#team2').html(options); //<----else show all the options
     }
   });
});
```

[Fiddle for updated one](http://jsfiddle.net/7dxtd/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem that I don't want remove the team in the second list. I just hide (the team that I selected in the 1st list) in the second list. Can you edit your code to do that please. Best regards

Comment: @user3149518 see the updates

Comment: thank you for this update but there is a problem when I select Italia, there is also Italia in the second list. Just when I select the 1 team, hide this team in the second. But the script have a problem..

Comment: have you checked the fiddle? may be you are not putting your script inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` block.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but the script of @Danijel is correct

Comment: if you could be more specific about your issue then you would get your answer quite fast, nonetheless great we helped you for this.